# Audio CD source plugin for .wav files . Linux

Tags: audio, music, music-player, audio-cd, wav

I have a CD which contains a number of .wav files.

When I try to open one I get:

> The playback of this movie requires a Audio CD source plugin which is not installed.

Can someone please sent me a link to what I should download and install to play these files?

My OS is Scientific Linux 32 bit .

Comment: What app are you trying to open these in? I would use something like `mplayer` from the command line.

Comment: Are you certain that your CD is full of wav files? I have used at least one file manager that arbitrarily attached a ".wav" extension when viewing the contents of an audio CD. VLC should also be able to play wav files (on a data disc) and true Red Book audio CDs as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu or any derivative(Mint), install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` from the software centre. It should contain plugins to play any audio/video file you want. Fedora, OpenSuse, and Arch also have audio/video plugins(next time mention your specs in the question). If that does not work, you can always install `vlc` from the software centre.